# Plane Boolean modifier doesn't see a text object

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to do a title and credits in a way of a simple motion graphic text reveal but when I add a modifier to a plane it doesn't see any text object to apply a difference operation to. [image: demonstration of the absence of the text object in the object list]

Comment: Convert the text to mesh first. Alt+c> curve to mesh.

Comment: Text is not a mesh, but a curve object. You can't do booleans with curves.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain in more detail? Do I have to press Alt+c with text object selected? Doing that doesn't seem to have any effect and I'm not a confident user of Blender unfortunately to understand half of the things.

Comment: @cegaton I'm not doing boolean with a text, it is a plane which is selected